# Installed Ubuntu Server, then Kubuntu package: Some problems

Tags: server, kubuntu

I recently installed Ubuntu server x64; I then realized there was no window manager built in (in retrospect it makes sense, didn't think of it at the time).

I have been having recurring crash report messages (system remains functional though) mainly before a shutdown or on login. As in general in Linux I don't think it is something normal, I am thinking If I am doing something wrong or how I could investigate further.

I am wondering whether going for the x64 and/or Ubuntu server + kubuntu package might have left some problems behind.

From my past experience with another UNIX o/s (FreeBSD) I never had crash issues.

Comment: What are the problems? Can you be more specific on that point? It would be helpful

Comment: I will provide printsreens with the error messageboxes later today.

Answer (score 1):

Without more detail (as "Olive Twist" asked) it is hard to tell what is wrong.
Are you seeing kernel Oops messages?

My own experience has shown that X-Windows driver problems can cause a Linux system to freeze or at least cause the console (mouse and keyboard) to freeze. (But these are hard errors that stop the system not what you seem to be describing)